# Emulating google search on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, google-search

I am trying to emulate google search using elasticsearch. 
When I search for "My name is kalam" in google, it shows results of "I am kalam" movie. How is google search able to provide this result and how is google checking for relevance of data searched? Is this implementable in elasticsearch as well?

Comment: It's an industry secret! Look into Natural Language Processing

Comment: for this specific case you can use synonyms ( my name is => i am ). But I think your question is broader =)

Comment: @PierreMallet what  are the different features that are usually used in this type of search?

Comment: suggestions, fault tolerance and usually a big fat load of ranking engineering :D but im no google search engineer. I you want some advice you should for the beginning collect the uses case you want to handle. Them we could give you direction on how handle those cases with elasticsearch